# Requirements for public posts to be searchable with facebook graph search API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, privacy

**Are there any privacy settings which will cause a conflict with a post marked as public, causing it to not be returned by facebook graph api seraches?**

According to documentation, *"You can search over all public objects in the social graph"*, including *"all public posts"*. It appears some accounts have wall and timeline posts marked to public, however, none ever show in the returned resultset from graph api search calls.

I'm using the facebook graph search api, using the endpoint URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/search

**Regular behavior:**

Test queries like https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bacon&type=post will of course give results. Making public posts with unusual words makes them easily searchable, which is useful for testing purposes.

**Problem:**

Public statuses with distinct terms should be findable with the graph api ( at least some of the time ). Some users, however, appear to consistently never have any of their public posts included in results in queries that target them.

Answer (score 0):

The only other privacy setting that could affect this is the `Public search` setting (found under Ads, Apps and Websites). Its the option that hides you from Facebook Search completely. This setting is opt-in so it really depends on how many of the user's with missing status updates have this setting disabled (i.e. hidden from search).

Comment: My personal account has that option enabled, yet my own posts as well as some coworkers yield no results.

Comment: It could be a caching issue in that case. Wait for facebook to update it's cache for that keyword (maybe a day or two) and see if it works then.

Comment: Some posts from multiple users posting with the same terms showed up right away for some users, while others were excluded. I can do some longer-term testing, though.